# Check all CheckBoxes inside a ListBox in a loop c#

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox

I have the following Code:

```
<ListBox Name="lstCheckBoxes" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxKlimaanlage" Content="Klimaanlage"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxSensor"   Content="Sensor"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxDigital"  Content="Digital"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAnalog"   Content="Analog"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere1"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere2"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere3"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere4"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere5"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere6"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere7"  Content="Anderes"/>
    <CheckBox Name="CheckboxAndere8"  Content="Anderes"/>
</ListBox>
```

and the issue is that I want to check every Checkbox inside the ListBox with a loop and save the content from the active boxes in something like a list.

I already saw some code like .. `foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)`..
but the `.Controls` won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Controls` property comes from WinForms project controls, I suppose

If you take a wpf Panel (Grid, StackPanel) - they have `Children`

but ListBox isn't a Panel, it is an ItemsControl and has `Items`

```
foreach (CheckBox c in lstCheckBoxes.Items)
{
    if (c.IsChecked == true)
    {
    }
}
```

it also has `ItemsSource` property, which can be set via binding. I recommend to read about MVVM in WPF, to use `ItemsSource` bound to a view model property.

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you ! But How can i save the Checkbox Content as a String in something like a List ?

Comment: @Morta, assuming you have a list (`var L = new List<string>();`) declared somewhere *before* foreach loop, add text from Content property: `L.Add(c.Content.ToString());`